# sci fi story set in the future - An Olympic swimmer genetically modifies his daughter to have webbed fingers

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

It was a story set in the future, about an Olympic swimmer who genetically modifies his baby girl to get webbed fingers, so that she excels at swimming better than him. But, the girl, as she grows, starts hating swimming and finds interest in Piano instead - where she needs long and free fingers !

Comment: This sounds familiar, but I can't find it or think of any details to add.

Comment: This has just a touch to do with your question ; but I thought it might be interesting that in the same sense cats on the Eastern Seabord (New England through the Maritimes) show higher rates of polydactylism; so too do humans show a similar ratio of syndactlyly

Comment: @alphaapple I haven't looked at this in depth, but increased rates of polydactyly and syndactyly may be founder effects from a limited gene pool of the first settlers—and their cats.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chance you mean *Nothing in the Rules?* Written by L. Sprague de Camp, it has some of the elements you're looking for.

> Swimming coach Louis Connaught, has entered his prize discovery Maria Santalucia in a women's swim meet in expectation of the usual victory; as Mrs. Santalucia, born with webbed fingers, has an advantage over the other swimmers. Then his arch-rival, coach Herbert Laird, arrives, causing a strange commotion. When Connaught sees why he shouts a strenuous protest.

It's the closest I've been able to find so far. Let me know, and I'll keep looking in the meanwhile.